# Es necesario descargar una iso especial para un servidor de kali linux?

Tags: servidor

Debo para un proyecto instalar Kali Linux para un servidor pero he trabajado poco con SO de distibución libre y necesito ayuda para instalarlo y configurarlo. Si tienen información de como instalarlo pero como servidor no como maquina normal y en VirtualBox les agradecería mucho.

Comment: Deberías consultar primero la documentación de la distro que mencionas. No parece esto una pregunta relacionada con la programación o herramientas relacionadas, sino como informática general.

Comment: Te recomiendo consultar en https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Kali Linux es una distribución desarrollada solamemnte para Desktop por lo cual no tiene versión especifica para Server, pero se puede usar sin problemas es un servidor ya que es base Debian, solamente debe instalarlo como si fuera Desktop, en el siguiente link esta la explicación paso a paso de como instalarlo:
https://backtrackacademy.com/articulo/instalando-kali-linux

Adicionalmente desde el siguiente link puede descargar el archivo .ova (Tanto VirtualBox como VMWare) directamente desde la página de Kali/Offensive Security en el cual ya viene instalado:
https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download